# HTML Linking Between Pages Without Refreshing Specific Parts

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

Firstly, I am designing UI of a hybrid mobile application with cordova. I need to implement a basic app feature into this application. You can see the demonstration [HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvqgyy). What I want to do is something almost like in the Facebook Android app. I have Menu 1 - Menu 2 and Menu 3 and a content part as you can see. I want the both header parts NOT to be refreshed when I switched between Menus (The switching can be done by swiping if possible or just touching as a basic link) And here my questions now;

1. I think this can be done by means of iFrame but I don't think iFrame is a good solution for mobile, isn't it?
2. If iFrame is really a bad solution for mobile, can I do it in another way just with HTML - CSS or any kind of Javascript library?
3. Is it better to have 3 different html pages to switching between than having only one html page with different 3 sections? Which one would be the best way?

Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="main-header">Main Header</header>
    <header class="subheader">
        <div class="menu"><a href="" class="active">MENU 1</a></div>
        <div class="menu"><a href="">MENU 2</a></div>
        <div class="menu"><a href="">MENU 3</a></div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br>HERE IS THE CONTENT PART<br></div>
</div>

    .wrapper {
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}

header.main-header {
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:orange;
    position:fixed;
    line-height:40px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:"Verdana";
    text-align:center;
}

header.subheader {
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:orange;
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
}

header.subheader .menu a{
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:47px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:"Verdana";
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}

header.subheader .menu a.active {
    border-bottom:3px solid red;
}

header.subheader .menu a:hover {
    border-bottom:3px solid red;
}

.content {
    margin-top:100px;
    padding:25px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say for sure as you haven't really defined what you want the menus to do, but you can most likely achieve what you want using the CSS `:hover` psuedo-class.

Comment: The menus need to behave just like Facebook Android app. I  think that is clear enough.